# Mockito cannot mock class as it cannot instrument interface

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

I am new to Mockito and trying to test a model class by mocking the repositories it is using. When doing so, I get following exception by Mockito (example, applies for all repositories I'm using):

```
Underlying exception : org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Cannot instrument interface [...].CRUDRepositoryJPA because it or one of its supertypes could not be initialized
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Mockito cannot mock this class: class [..].BookRepository.
```

Do I need to handle/mock the interfaces somehow, too?

Test Class:

```
public ModelTest{
    @Mock
    private BookRepository bookRepository = mock(BookRepository.class);
    [...]

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        model = new ClientModel();

        when(bookRepository.readAll()).thenReturn(TestConfig.defaultBooks());
        [...]

        model.readRepositories();
    }

    @Test
    [...]
}
```

Repository Class:

```
public class BookRepository implements CRUDRepositoryJPA<Book> {
    [...]
}
```

Interfaces:

```
public interface CRUDRepositoryJPA<T> extends CRUDRepository<T> {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Config.DB_NAME);
}

public interface CRUDRepository<T> {
    void create(T t);
    Optional<T> readById(long id);
    List<T> readAll();
    void update(T t);
    void delete(T t);
}
```

Test dependencies (Mockito 5.2.1):

```
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.+'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.+'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:5.+'
```

System info from exception:

```
Java               : 19
JVM vendor name    : Amazon.com Inc.
JVM vendor version : 19.0.1+10-FR
JVM name           : OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
JVM version        : 19.0.1+10-FR
JVM info           : mixed mode
OS name            : Mac OS X
OS version         : 13.3
```

Expected repository classes to be mockable, e.g. readAll() for model initialization that requires these methods.

Comment: Everything looks fine, but one thing is bothering me here: `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory` in the `CRUDRepositoryJPA` - this is something unusual in interface and might be some problem for mockito. Try to refactor this to not have this emf in the interface

Comment: Indeed, thank you. When I get rid of `CRUDRepositoryJPA`completely, put single `emf`instances in the respective repositories, then don't instantiate those in my model but rather pass a new dedicated 'RepositoryModel' class/object responsible for repository instantiation & provision to the model itself (which I can mock), then tests run successfully. Not quite sure if this is the most elegant/best way to solve it, but thanks already!